# Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to number (PHP | MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, mariadb

I'm sorry if this question is duplicate or has been asked before. I've read some references on the internet, but still don't get it.

So, I have a `transaction` table:

| id | customer | qty | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cus1 | 5 | 2021-04-01 |
| 2 | cus2 | 3 | 2021-04-01 |
| 3 | cus3 | 7 | 2021-04-02 |

I want to take all the `qty` data where `date` = "**2021-04-01**", then I want to sum it. So, I'm using the following code:

```
$qty = $db->query("SELECT SUM(`qty`) FROM `transaction` WHERE `date` = '2021-04-01'");
```

> *Note: the $db variable is the connection function to the database*

Next, I want to multiply the results of the query, as follows:

```
$profit = $qty * 10;
```

And when I run the code I get an error message:

```
Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to number
```

How do I fix it? All I want is to multiply the query result from the variable `$qty` (`$qty * 10`)

I am a beginner. Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your SQL query to alias the aggregation for easy access.

```
$qty = $db->query("SELECT SUM(`qty`) as 'val_sum' FROM `transaction` WHERE `date` = '2021-04-01'");
```

You can cast a string to an int with "(int) $string_value"

```
if ($qty->num_rows > 0) {
   $row = $qty->fetch_assoc()
   $profit = (int) $row['val_sum'] * 10;
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates.